# SDL in XCode 4.3.2 SDLMain.o undefined symbols

Tags: xcode, sdl, undefined, symbols

I have started trying to use SDL in Xcode 4.3.2 so I started up a Cocoa application for Mac OS X and connected all my frameworks : OpenGL, SDL etc. I don't have SDL_Image, SDL_Mixer etc. (Do I need these?) When I try to compile the project that just has SDLmain.h and SDLmain.m I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_SDL_main", referenced from: -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in SDLMain.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue with SDL 1.2.15 on Xcode 4.5 and OS X 10.7, turned out the problem was that I added `SDLMain.m` and `SDLMain.h` (according to a suggestion on the libSDL website about OS X frameworks) to an existing SDL project which messed up with `main`. Bottom line is that you don't need those files just because you are using Cocoa -- SDL's own test apps don't use it either and run just fine on OS X.