# install SDL on QT

Tags: c++, qt, sdl

i trying it nearly 5 hours and still cannot setup to run helloWorld SDL on QT. please help me.
1) first of all i download from site developer package
SDL2-devel-2.0.1-mingw.tar.gz (MinGW 32/64-bit)
and there i686 and simple x86, which of them i need to add ?
i download this package

2) then i add all bin, lib, include in 
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\mingw47_32

my Pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../5.0.2/mingw47_32/include

## Glut / OpenGL
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../5.0.2/mingw47_32/lib/ -lglut32
unix|win32: LIBS += -lOPENGL32
```

When i start app, get error.

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\Tools\QtCreator\bin\check_sdl\main.cpp:10: ошибка: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
```

When in Pro file add rows

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\SDL2-2.0.1\\i686-w64-mingw32\\include"
LIBS += -L"C:\\SDL2-2.0.1\\i686-w64-mingw32\\lib\\" \
-lmingw32\
-libSDL2main.a\
-lSDL2_test.a\
```

then error is

```
:-1: ошибка: cannot find -libSDL2main.a
```

however this file are there .
[image]

so i have no idea what to do :/

**UPDATE:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\SDL2-2.0.1\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include\\SDL2"
LIBS += -L"C:\\SDL2-2.0.1\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\bin\\SDL2"
```

again undefined SDL Q_Q

**UPDATE 2:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
LIBS += -L"C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" \
-lmingw32\
-lSDL2main\
-lSDL2\


#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

\Users\slouken\release\SDL\SDL2-2.0.1-source\src\main\windows\SDL_windows_main.c:140: ошибка: undefined reference to `SDL_main'
```

**UPDATE 3**
Now it's running, but crashing on start)

```
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL_main.h"
//#include "SDL.h"


#undef main

using namespace std;

//int main()
//int main(int, char**)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    cout << "hell";
    int i = 4 +4 ;
    cout << "i is: " << i;

    //Quit SDL
   // SDL_Quit();

   return 0;
}
```

Crash with error 0x00000135

Comment: omit the .a extension: -lSDL2main . Also, the order on the linker line matters when it comes to static libs.

Comment: please checkout update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both SDL and Qt provide OpenGL drawing surfaces - why do you need SDL when you already use Qt?

anyway, that

```
undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
```

is a linker error, and it happens because you have `-libSDL2main.a` instead of `-lSDL2main` in your flags, so the file and it's symbols are not found.

### first update:

```
undefined reference to `SDL_main'
```

this might be a signature mismatch.

You should declare the main function with the usual `int main(int, char**)` signature, because the arguments are important for SDL, as it tries to capture them.

Check this answer:
[SDL Error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 "_SDL_main"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543150/sdl-error-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-sdl-main)

### second update:

0x00000135 means *DLL not found* (at runtime).

You can use this tool (http://dependencywalker.com) to check if all the libraries are being found - maybe some unsatisfied mingw support library dependency is killing your program.

Comment: it's suprising, but i have needed main, i uncomment this and no way

Comment: 0x00000135 means DLL not found (at runtime)

http://www.dependencywalker.com/
get a suitable version for you operating system and check if all the libraries are being found - maybe some unsatisfied mingw support library dependency is killing your program.  happened to me before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's give answers what's was my troubles.

1. I was using wrong x86_64-w64-mingw32. I needed to use
   i686-w64-mingw32
2. Forgot to add SDL2.dll into C:/Windows or into folder with *.exe
3. right main is " int main(int argc, char* argv[]) "
4. Right paths are :

   ```
   INCLUDEPATH += C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include
   LIBS += -L"C:\SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib" \
   -lmingw32\
   -lSDL2main\
   -lSDL2\
   ```
5. also dependency walker told me to add libwinpthread-1.dll, i also
   add this into folder.

Thanks all for help!